# Pandoc: Include raw `tex` in `markdown` to `html` conversion

Tags: html, markdown, mathjax, pandoc

Here is a simple markdown code:

```
$$ \alpha = \beta\label{eqone}$$
Refer equation (\ref{eqone}).
```

When I convert this to html using

```
pandoc --mathjax file.markdown -o file.html
```

the `\ref{eqone}` is omitted in the `html` output since it is raw tex. Is there a work around to include the raw tex in html output?

I understand that I could have used:

```
(@eqone) $$\alpha=\beta$$
Refer equation ((@eqone)).
```

for equation numbering and referencing. This produces the number on the left side and also does not distinguish between figures, tables and equations.

However, `mathjax` numbering appears on the right like the standard `tex` output.

Any other work around for proper equation numbering is also welcome.

Note: Following code needs to be added to the head of the generated `html` file to configure autonumbering in `mathjax`.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "all"} } });
</script>
```

Comment: @A.Donda Thanks. It was a very good guess. I should have thought about this. Please add this as an answer. Using `$ $` works for `html` output and one can post-process the `latex` output with sed to remove the `$` signs for all references.

Comment: I deleted the comment and made an answer with the same contents. Glad I could help. :-) Using sed is a good idea. Did you try `$\text{\ref{eqone}}$`, too? – Btw. there's a `--mathjax` option to pandoc. It only inserts the link to the javascript, but it would make sense if it also enabled preserving other kinds of embedded LaTeX that MathJax supports.

Comment: @A.Donda Haven't tried `$\text$` since I am happy with the only `$ $`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put the `\ref` into a math environment, `$\ref{eqone}$`. And if the command is not defined in math, switch back to text, `$\text{\ref{eqone}}$`. Ugly, but it might work.